# html event focus not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body onload="getfocus()">
<input id='txt1' />
<input type="button" onblur="getfocus()" value="Test"/>
<script>
function getfocus(){
    document.getElementById("txt1").focus();    
}
</script>
</body>
```

In the above code, getfocus() works as expected on body onload but onBlur of button it doesn't work as expected i.e. txt1 doesn't get focus.

kindly, let me know why txt1 is not getting focused on 'onblur' event.

Comment: I believe it must have focus first...why don't you just target `#txt1` onload instead? Adding `tab-index='1'` to `#txt1` might help as well.

Comment: onload it already working. I want txt1 to be focused after onblur of button.

Comment: You need to focus on the input first, otherwise it'll never trigger a blur event.

Comment: its already done on body onload event

Comment: Sorry, it's late where I'm at. See my example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `tab-index` attribute to `#txt1`, otherwise your browser will tab *out* of the document (which for me using Chrome went to the address bar).

```
<body onload="getfocus()">
    <input id='txt1' tab-index="1" />
    <input type="button" onblur="getfocus()" value="Test"/>
    <script>
        function getfocus(){
            document.getElementById("txt1").focus();    
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

As an aside, you'll notice that if you add another arbitrary third `input` after the second one, it will start working too.

Comment: Thanks Matt !!! It worked after adding third input. It would be great if you can explain why this is working after adding 3rd input.

Comment: Great. When you add a third input, your tab 'state' is still within the DOM (because it has another element to tab in to); this means that `getfocus` still has control over your tab state. Without the third input, the tab state moves outside the DOM to your web browsers GUI.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

Try adding `onblur='getfocus()` on `#txt` and `onclick="getfocus()"` on the button.

#### SNIPPET

It seems that `tab-index='1'` works great.`

```html
<body onload="getfocus()">
  <input id='txt1' tab-index='1' onblur='getfocus()' />
  <input type="button" onclick="getfocus()" value="Test" />
  <script>
    function getfocus() {
      document.getElementById("txt1").focus();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but i want on 'onBlur' event and not on click of button